# How to convert a BSpline/PPoly object into an array of polynomials/list

Tags: python, interpolation, spline, polynomials

I'm working on a small project here in my uni where I have to create a program that, based on data from a .txt file, perfmorms a certain Method (root finding, interpolaltion, derivation, etc) and pastes the results in another .txt file.
Thing is, I can't get it to work on the Cubic Spline method since the function `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline` returns an object of the *BSpline* class, and I need it as an array with the coefficients to be able to add it to the .txt file.

I looked around the SciPy library to look for a solution and found the `interpolate.PPoly.from_spline()` function but it's still not what I need; I don't know how to convert a BSpline or a PPoly class object into a Numpy array
I'm pretty much a beginner with these kinds of things so any help to make it work is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `PPoly.from_spline()` can be a bit confusing, but it is still probably what you need.
I'll go through a simple example to explain.

The following code builds an interpolation cubic spline of the function `y(t)=t**2`:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y = t**2
bsp = make_interp_spline(t, y)
```

The interpolation of the five points will result in a cubic B-Spline with the knot vector `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1]` as can be seen if you `print(bsp.t)`. This is a specific case of a clamped cubic B-Spline where the first and last four knots are multiplied.
Going into the details of the B-Spline representation is out of the scope of this answer. I recommend reading about it in the many references out there, for example in [this online course](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html) by Shene.

Running the following command will give you a `PPoly` object as you suggested.

```
poly = PPoly.from_spline(bsp)
```

Now we can analyze the result to understand what's going on.
From [the documentation of `PPoly`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.html) it has two relevant attributes: `poly.x` are the breakpoints between polynomials, and `poly.c` are the coefficients of the polynomials in **local power basis**.

The local power basis is important to notice, it means the i'th polynomial is represented in the variable `(x-x[i])` (and not in the variable `x` as maybe one might expect). As the documentation says "the polynomial between `x[i]` and `x[i + 1]` is written:"

```
S = sum(c[m, i] * (xp - x[i])**(k-m) for m in range(k+1))
```

Now let's see how this is demonstrated in our example.
`poly.c` is a numpy array of (local) coefficients of shape `(4, 8)`. The 4 comes from number of coefficients of each (cubic) polynomial. The 8 is a bit more confusing. However, if you print `poly.x` you will see it is `[0,0,0,0, 0.5, 1,1,1,1]` (taken from bsp's knot vector), so 8 is the number of intervals `[x[i], x[i+1]]` of domains on which the polynomials are defined.
In this example (and probably every example taken from a clamped B-Spline) the first and last three intervals are degenerate.

If we print the coefficients using `print(poly.c.T)` (I use the transpose of the coefficient array since it's easier to understand) we'll get the following (on my machine, your's may slightly vary):

```
[[ 1.62832710e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.10358047e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.62832710e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.10358047e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.62832710e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.10358047e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.62832710e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.10358047e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [-3.55271368e-15  1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  2.50000000e-01]
 [-3.55271368e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]
 [-3.55271368e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]
 [-3.55271368e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
```

As I said above, the first and last three (degenerate) intervals can be ignored in our context, so let's look at the fourth and fifth lines.

Line 4 gives the coefficients of the interval `[0, 0.5]` and they are basically `[0, 1, 0, 0]`. These correspond to the polynomial:

```
0*(x-0)**3 + 1*(x-0)**2 + 0*(x-0) + 0*1 = x**2
```

So we get that on the interval `[0, 0.5]` the interpolating polynomial is `x**2` as expected (since a cubic spline interpolates `x**2` exactly).

Similarly, line 5 gives the coefficients of the interval `[0.5, 1]` and they are basically `[0, 1, 1, 0.25]`. These correspond to the polynomial:

```
0*(x-0.5)**3 + 1*(x-0.5)**2 + 1*(x-0.5) + 0.25*1
```

And when expanding the terms we get (again as expected) `x**2`.

So, basically, after getting a `PPoly` object from a spline using `from_spline()` you can get a numpy array of the *local basis* polynomial coefficients over the i'th interval using `poly.c[:, i]`. If you need the non-local coefficients, you need to expand the local basis from `(x-x[i])` to `x` as demonstrated above.